# Is there a "description" field for Rules actions?

Tags: rules

I have several rules that are very complicated and have many steps.  Even though I am the only web developer, I often have to study rules I have written a bit to remember how they work.

Does the Rules module have "description" fields somewhere like Views so developers can make notes to other developers/themselves?  Surely other people must have this same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so needed.  I agree.  Luckily, it's in the works: http://drupal.org/node/1244738

I'd add your vote to that Drupal module issue!  :-)